# Approaching a Trajectory Problem

Tags: trigonometry, physics, runge-kutta-methods

I am trying to design a railgun simulation. The idea is that the user can supply a starting point and velocity vector for a launcher and for a target, and the launcher will find the angle to launch the projectile at. I previously created a program that would model a roman candle's projectile motion with wind resistance by using a Runge-Kutta ODE, in 2D. Now I pretty much want to work backwards from that. I however have a few questions about how to approach this problem:

1. Is it possible to work backwards using this ODE as a model? I am under the assumption that the answer is no, and I'll have to brute-force it by sweeping through different angles (perhaps solving the trajectory without wind resistance and using that angle as a starting point?)
2. In terms of computation time, using multi-threading, solving for theta in a 2D system shouldn't be too bad. However, assuming the only way to solve the problem is sweeping through values, this seems to get complicated when trying to compute a 3D system. These are the equations I found online:

> x = cos(theta) * cos(phi)
>
> y = sin(theta) * cos(phi)
>
> z = sin(phi)

Now there's two sets of values to sweep through (as if a theta is found, the values of x and y will change when sweeping through phi values). So this is especially where a better method for finding the angles would be beneficial.

If it helps at all, this was the general form of Runge-Kutta used in the previous program:
$$q_{1x}= f_{x}(t_{k}, v_{xak}, v_{y})$$
$$q_{1y}= f_{y}(t_{k}, v_{xak}, v_{y})$$
$$q_{2x}= f_{x}(t_{k} + \frac {\Delta t}{2} , v_{xak} + \frac {\Delta tq_{1x}}{2} , v_{y} + \frac {\Delta tq_{1y}}{2})$$
$$q_{2y}= f_{x}(t_{k} + \frac {\Delta t}{2} , v_{xak} + \frac {\Delta tq_{1x}}{2} , v_{y} + \frac {\Delta tq_{1y}}{2})$$
$$q_{3x}= f_{x}(t_{k} + \frac {\Delta t}{2} , v_{xak} + \frac {\Delta tq_{2x}}{2} , v_{y} + \frac {\Delta tq_{2y}}{2})$$
$$q_{3y}= f_{x}(t_{k} + \frac {\Delta t}{2} , v_{xak} + \frac {\Delta tq_{2x}}{2} , v_{y} + \frac {\Delta tq_{2y}}{2})$$
$$q_{4x}= f_{x}(t_{k} + \Delta t , v_{xak} + \Delta tq_{3x}, v_{y} + \Delta tq_{3y})$$
$$q_{4y}= f_{y}(t_{k} + \Delta t , v_{xak} + \Delta tq_{3x}, v_{y} + \Delta tq_{3y})$$
$$v_{x(k+1)}= v_{xk} + \frac {\Delta t}{6}(q_{1x} + 2q_{2x} + 2q_{3x} + q_{4x})$$
$$v_{y(k+1)}= v_{yk} + \frac {\Delta t}{6}(q_{1y} + 2q_{2y} + 2q_{3y} + q_{4y})$$

Where:
$$f_{x}(t, v_{xa}, v_{y})=\frac{dv_{x}}{dt} = -\frac{F_{D}v_{xa}}{mv}$$

And:
$$f_{y}(t, v_{xa}, v_{y})=\frac{dv_{y}}{dt} = -g-\frac{F_{D}v_{y}}{mv}$$

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks, Nic

Comment: Why do you need a third dimension? Are you factoring in wind having a direction as opposed to just air resistance? If not just find the right bearing to aim at then solve it in the 2D vertical slice between cannon and target. If you are having the wind able to push your projectile off alignment then you make the problem much, much harder - is the projectile a point? or a sphere? or some complicated geometry? all these will be affected by wind.

Comment: What is a railgun?

Comment: @IanMiller Yes, I was thinking of having a wind vector. I should clarify, the software I wrote before had wind moving in the +/-x direction, not just resisting the movement of the projectile. The problem with finding the right bearing is that I'm not sure how I would find that, as the target is moving and of course the velocity of the projectile is not constant due to the wind resistance.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN A railgun is a type of launcher that uses a type of force called Lorentz Force, which is induced because of a electromagnetic field.

Comment: @IanMiller Oh, and I was thinking of a generic missile shape. I was using [this](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/802065.pdf) to assist me with an approximation.

Comment: Once you give your projectile a missile shape you have actually turned this into a 6D problem as you have 3 axes of rotation as well (if you projectile is cylindrically symmetrical then its really only 5D as you can ignore rotations on that axis). This becomes harder yet again and will require numerical techniques to solve. For your first go at this I'd recommend a spherical projectile so it is only a 3D problem.